# How do I create an applet that accesses a word under the mouse from any window like three-finger-tap (Ctrl-Cmd-D) dictionary popup?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, hover, shortcut

OSX allows you to hover your mouse cursor over a word in almost any app and three-finger-tap (or Ctrl-Cmd-D) to create a dictionary popup with the word.

How can I create a similar popup that accesses a word (or preferably any arbitrary string) under the mouse cursor?